# How do you translate "I always drink coffee with cream"?

Tags: translation, grammar

I'm particularly interested in how you translate "with" here.

I remember someone using it in a conversation yesterday, but didn't get the chance to have them repeat it. I tried searching MDBG and Chinese Grammar Wiki but found nothing useful. I also searched Chinese StackExchange, but "with" is such a common word that I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Please include some homework, i.e.: what you've tried? Why didn't it help? etc.

Comment: I remember someone using it in a conversation yesterday, but didn't get the chance to have them repeat it. I tried searching MDBG and Chinese Grammar Wiki but found nothing useful. I also searched Chinese StackExchange, but "with" is such a common word that I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: You can edit your question with the *edit* button above, and include that paragraph you left as a comment here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"with" here means "contains" or "have"

"with cream" in "coffee with cream" is an adjectival phrase that describe the noun coffee.

> I drink coffee
>
> what coffee?
>
> the coffee that's with cream

I always drink coffee  = 我总是喝咖啡

I always drink coffee (**with cream**) = 我一向喝(**加了奶油的**)咖啡 or 我一向喝(**有奶油的**)咖啡

*If you are having a cup of black coffee and a cup of cream at the same time, then 'with' would mean "together" and coffee and cream would be of equal weight. That is not what the sentence in your question meant. in "I always drink coffee with cream",  coffee is the main object, cream is an addition*

**More example of "with" meaning "contains"  or "have"**

"book with pictures" (book that contains pictures)

"people with money" ( people who have money)

Comment: Thanks. Is 我总是喝咖啡加奶油 also correct? I think the person I was talking to (a native speaker) said that.

Comment: @telotortium both 一向 and 总是 mean 'always' .  一向 implies it is your routine or habit; 总是  implies it is an observation of your behavior

Answer (score 1):

all attributes are added before nonus in Chinese. or you must start a new sentence to describe it. so you may not find a word that correspond one to one with "with".

Answer (score 0):

我总是喝带奶油的咖啡。
with means 带。
In Chinese, with could be translated to 用，带有